# C - how can I set an array pointer back to the first memory byte

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have an array of pointers to struct, and after processing the array, the pointer is at the end of the memory block. I want to free memory block, so I need to go to the first memory byte and loop through the array of pointers again to free each of the elements in the array. How would you point back to the first byte of the memory block?

Comment: Why don't you just make a copy of your original pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an automatic way - you have to pass the original location to free.

Common techniques are to make a copy of the original pointer or if you know the number of entries and their size you can just subtract this from the pointer

Answer (score 7):

You have to either remember the original address or know where you are (what index) so you can back up enough to find the start.

An example of the first (ignoring for now that, in all these cases, you're printing uninitialised values, it is a *contrived* example after all):

```
int *ip = malloc (10 * sizeof (*ip));

int *origIp = ip;

printf ("%d\n", *ip++);  // print and advance
printf ("%d\n", *ip++);  // print and advance

ip = origIp; free (ip);  // or just free (origIp) if you wish.
```

For the second:

```
int *ip = malloc (10 * sizeof (*ip));

int idx = 0;

printf ("%d\n", *ip++); idx++;  // print and advance
printf ("%d\n", *ip++); idx++;  // print and advance

ip -= idx; free (ip);
```

Alternatively, you could just keep your pointer as is and use array indexing to process the array, something like:

```
int *ip = malloc (10 * sizeof (*ip));

int idx = 0;

printf ("%d\n", ip[idx++]);  // print and advance
printf ("%d\n", ip[idx++]);  // print and advance

free (ip);
```

Most modern compilers will give you the same code under the covers anyway.